# substrings in multiple pandas series

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to find a way to search for substrings in strings for a problem like this

```
findin = pd.Series({1:'abcab', 2: 'abab',3: 'abcdaa', 4:'cabca'})
what = pd.Series({1:'b',2: 'a',3: 'bc',4: 'abc'})
```

where "what" is what I am seeking and "findin" is the values I want to search 
I would like the output to be something like

```
1 4
0 3 
1
1
```

Every method I have tried is upset at the different number of values that come out.  I keep getting "Data must be 1-dimensional" for example using methods like

```
list(map(lambda x, y: x.find(y), findin, what))
```

I feel like expand needs to be here, but where does it go?

Comment: It's unclear how you get your output. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: the output is the location of substring "what" in the string"findin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex in a function and apply if on `findin` Series:

```
c = iter(range(1, 5))

def func(x):
    ind = next(c)
    return [i.start() for i in re.finditer(what[ind], x)]

findin.apply(func)
```

Out:

```
1    [1, 4]
2    [0, 2]
3       [1]
4       [1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted! I need to become better friends with the iters....